# Inconsistent behavior of classes as shortcuts/apps in Android 4.1+?

Tags: android, android-widget, shortcut

I made two apps, each one has classes that I want to use as shortcuts or independent apps (equally fine with me). They worked fine in Android 4.0.3, but not in 4.1+.

The fist app is called `xvf`, and has a  class `FolderList` (named `Fima`) that I want to make into a shortcut. The other app is `ave` that has a class `ViewMap` (named `Ave Map`) that I want as a shortcut too. However, I have two problems:

1) I cannot add the shortcut to the home screen in 4.1+. I find the shortcut inside "Widgets", but when I release the shortcut in the home screen, instead of placing the icon, the class is executed as if it was clicked, and it is not added.

2) `Fima` appears as an independent app in Android 4.4 and not as a shortcut, so I was able to add it, but appears as a widget in Android 4.1.2... Why `Fima` appears as an independent app???

This is the relevant part of both manifests:

`xvf`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FolderList"
        android:label="Fima"
        android:icon="@drawable/fima_launcher_128"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeNonFS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`ave` Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewMap"
        android:label="Ave Map"
        android:icon="@drawable/guara_128"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeNonFS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/comma-separated-values" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/csv" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I make the shortcuts to work properly, or how do I make the classes to look as independent apps?

Thanks!!

L.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to this problem was to add

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

to the two activities. Now the second activity appears as an independent app, but at least now the icon stays in the HOME screen when released.